# VS code : #include<execution> :-#include errors detected. Please update your includePath

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, include, include-path

I am trying to include a header file in my Visual Studio "imtanan.cpp" file.
The header "#include" shows error

which says :-  "#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Imtanan CPP\imtanan.cpp).C/C++(1696)
cannot open source file "execution". Please run the 'Select IntelliSense Configuration...' command to locate your system headers.C/C++(1696)"

Some people on the internet are saying right click on the file imtanan.cpp in solution explorer and goto properties.
I have tried a lot  but there is no option "properties" when i right click there.

[This is my code inside imtanan.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC5k9.png)
Second Image:
[There is no option "properties" when i right-click on imtanan.cpp in the solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edrfb.png)
**Also tell me from where i can get execution file if we need that file to remove error.**
Please give me concise and convenient solution to that problem.

Thanks!

Some people on the internet are saying right click on the file imtanan.cpp in solution explorer and goto properties.
I have tried a lot  but there is no option "properties" when i right click there.